# $i not incrementing in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Following is my PHP code which is only giving `i =0` though in a loop I am incrementing the `$i` but it always return i as `0` and while loop is only working one time, though my query `SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE(event_date) < CURDATE()` is returning 7 records when exectuing in `phpmyadmin`. Let me know what i am doing wrong here ?

Code -

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/'."config.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if( $_POST['number'] == 'all' ) {
    $eventArr = array();
    $myarray = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE DATE(`event_date`) < CURDATE()";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $i =0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $eventArr[$i] = array('event_data'=> $row);

        // Get image For an event
        $event_id = $row['id'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM event_images WHERE event_id = $event_id ORDER BY `uploaded_date` DESC LIMIT 0,1";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $eventImgArr = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $eventImgArr[] = $row;
        }
        $eventArr[$i]['event_image'] = $eventImgArr;

        // Get venue details for the event
        $venue_id = $row['venue_id'];
        $eventVenArr = array();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `venues` WHERE id = $venue_id";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $eventVenArr[] = $row;
        }
        $eventArr[$i]['venue_detail'] = $eventVenArr;
        echo $i, " -- ";
        $i++;
    }
$myarray = array('response'=>'1','message'=>'Event data', 'data'=>$eventArr);
echo json_encode($myarray);
return;
}
```

Comment: also, you are not executing the query `SELECT * FROM venues WHERE id = $venue_id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are re-using the `$result` variable for the other queries, which is destroying its value needed for the main loop.

P.S. Also, you're not actually executing the query for the venue details.

Comment: @Boann After changing as per your suggestion to http://pastebin.com/nX2U0QKm I am getting error at line 31 -

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
<b>/home/events/my-show-event.php</b> on line 
<b>31</b>
<br />

Comment: A bolean is returned as `false` in this case. it means something is wrong with your query. Echo it out and check for its return in phpmyadmin. Try instead: `"SELECT * FROM event_images WHERE event_id = '".$event_id."' ORDER BY 'uploaded_date' DESC LIMIT 0,1";`